# Can methods of objects be intercepted when iterating over them as part of a collection?

Tags: php, oop, iterator, proxy-object

I'm wondering if an object belonging to a collection class, whilst being iterated on can know it's being iterated and know about the collection class it belongs to? e.g.

```
<?php
class ExampleObject
{
    public function myMethod()
    {
        if( functionForIterationCheck() ) {
           throw new Exception('Please do not call myMethod during iteration in ' . functionToGetIteratorClass());
        }
    }
}

$collection = new CollectionClass([
    new ExampleObject,
    new ExampleObject,
    new ExampleObject
]);

foreach($collection as $item) {
    $item->myMethod(); //Exception should be thrown.
}

(new ExampleObject)->myMethod(); //No Exception thrown.
```

I've done some Google'ing and couldn't find anything, I'm guessing it's not possible because it breaks an OOP principal somewhere but thought I'd ask anyway!

Comment: I don't think that is directly possible, but why would you need to throw an exception like that in the first place?

Comment: This design smells. I think there is a better solution, but first, you have to explain what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I won't argue it is a little stinky and the exception was just for the example. I'm looking into the possibility of writing a little auto-eager-load trait for Laravel so when a relationship is accessed during iteration it eager-loads the relationship for all items in the collection. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can inform the object about the collection by passing it as an argument to `MyMethod()`.

Comment: @axiac sorry I might have over simplified my example. The purpose is to do this on a Laravel Eloquent model when accessing a relationship which is done via magic methods so you access the method through a property, meaning I couldn't pass the Collection through. Also I wanted this to be automated rather than requiring the developer to pass the object through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can split this into the following problems:

1. We need to create a `Collection` that is iterable
2. The `Collection` should

   a. have the names of prohibited methods hard-coded (bad) *or*

   b. be able to fetch the names of prohibited methods from the elements of the collection
3. when iterating over the collection, it should yield proxies to the original object, intercepting calls to methods which should not be allowed to be called when iterating over the collection

#### 1) Collection should be iterable

This is easy, just make it implement the `Iterator` interface:

```
class Collection implements \Iterator
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $elements;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $key;

    public function __construct(array $elements)
    {
        // use array_values() here to normalize keys 
        $this->elements = array_values($elements);
        $this->key = 0;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return $this->elements[$this->key];
    }

    public function next()
    {
        ++$this->key;
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return $this->key;
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return array_key_exists(
            $this->key,
            $this->elements
        );
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->key = 0;
    }
}
```

#### 2) Collection should be able to fetch methods from elements

Rather than hard-coding the prohibited methods into the collection, I would suggest to create an interface, and have that be implemented by the elements of the collection, if need be, for example:

```
<?php

interface HasProhibitedMethods
{
    /**
     * Returns an array of method names which are prohibited 
     * to be called when implementing class is element of a collection.
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function prohibitedMethods();
}
```

This also has the advantage that the collection would work with all kinds of elements, as long as it is able to fetch that information from the element.

Then have your elements, if need be, implement the interface:

```
class Element implements HasProhibitedMethods
{ 
    public function foo()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        return 'bar';
    }

    public function baz()
    {
        return 'baz';
    }

    public function prohibitedMethods()
    {
        return [
            'foo',
            'bar',
        ];
    }
}
```

#### 3) When iterating, yield proxies

As suggested in a different answer by @akond, you could use [`ocramius/proxymanager`](https://github.com/ocramius/proxymanager), and specifically, an [*Access Interceptor Value Holder Proxy*](https://ocramius.github.io/ProxyManager/docs/access-interceptor-value-holder.html).

Run

```
$ composer require ocramius/proxymanager
```

to add it to your project.

Adjust the collection as follows:

```
<?php

use ProxyManager\Factory\AccessInterceptorValueHolderFactory;

class Collection implements \Iterator
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $elements;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $key;

    /**
     * @var AccessInterceptorValueHolderFactory
     */
    private $proxyFactory;

    public function __construct(array $elements)
    {
        $this->elements = array_values($elements);
        $this->key = 0;
        $this->proxyFactory = new AccessInterceptorValueHolderFactory();
    }

    public function current()
    {
        $element = $this->elements[$key];

        // if the element is not an object that implements the desired interface
        // just return it
        if (!$element instanceof HasProhibitedMethods) {
            return $element;
        }

        // fetch methods which are prohibited and should be intercepted
        $prohibitedMethods = $element->prohibitedMethods();

        // prepare the configuration for the factory, a map of method names 
        // and closures that should be invoked before the actual method will be called
        $configuration = array_combine(
            $prohibitedMethods,
            array_map(function ($prohibitedMethod) {
                // return a closure which, when invoked, throws an exception
                return function () use ($prohibitedMethod) {
                    throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf(
                        'Method "%s" can not be called during iteration',
                        $prohibitedMethod
                    ));
                };
            }, $prohibitedMethods)
        );

        return $this->proxyFactory->createProxy(
            $element,
            $configuration
        );
    }

    public function next()
    {
        ++$this->key;
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return $this->key;
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return array_key_exists(
            $this->key,
            $this->elements
        );
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->key = 0;
    }
}
```

#### Example

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php';

$elements = [
    new Element(),
    new Element(),
    new Element(),
];

$collection = new Collection($elements);

foreach ($collection as $element) {
    $element->foo();
}
```

**Note** This can still be optimized, for example, you could store references to the created proxies in the `Collection`, and instead of creating new proxies every time, `current()` could return previously created proxies, if need be.

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php
- https://github.com/ocramius/proxymanager
- https://ocramius.github.io/ProxyManager/docs/access-interceptor-value-holder.html

Comment: Thank for such a detailed response, this is super helpful.

Comment: Glad you like it, @scrwdnet!

Answer (score 1):

I should create two different classes in order to comply with single responsibility principle. One would be a `Collection`, and the other would be an `Object` itself. `Object`s get returned only as members of `Collection`. Every time when `Collection` gets iterated, it "loads" corresponding `Object`s.

If it seems appropriate, you might want to create [a Lazy loading ghost object proxy](https://ocramius.github.io/ProxyManager/docs/lazy-loading-ghost-object.html) for each of those `Object`s.

Comment: That link about ghost objects is actually really interesting, bit of an eye opener to something I hadn't come across/thought about before, thanks. I'll see if anyone else has other suggestions that might sit better within the existing Laravel code base before marking off as right :)